# Apache2 redirect domain to internal page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have two domains pointing to a site hosted by apache2 (a.com and b.com for example). The primary domain is a.com and the website can be accessed from this domain.

However, the page a.com/test/ should redirect to b.com (not b.com/test/) to display the content from the server and this content should also be displayed if b.com is accessed directly.

I thought that reverse proxies might be the way to go but haven't had any luck, I was wondering if this is possible to do within my .htaccess file (both domains are pointing to the server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need a reverse proxy. As long as both a.com and b.com's DNS point to the same apache server, you can set this up by just using vhosts and a redirect.

For the b.com vhost, just make it's `DocumentRoot` the test folder (full path). If that's not possible the you can also do this via htaccess.

For the redirect, add this to the htaccess file in a.com's document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} a\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ http://b.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

and for b.com if you can't set the `DocumentRoot` in the vhost

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} b\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^test/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! Will this still work if I'm using wordpress so the /test/ directory is already rewritten (because of wordpress' permalinks)?

Comment: If you're using wordpress, then removing part of the permalink will confuse wordpress and cause it to not work, for the second part (the b.com), you may need to look for a wordpress specific solution, like a plugin

Comment: Even if it is in htaccess, wordpress looks at the requested URI, and it won't see a `/test/` in the requested URI, so it'll return a 404. Doesn't matter what you do in htaccess.

Comment: I'm getting an internal server error when I try this, from the logs: `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.` Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Is there conflicts with wordpress rules or other mod rewrite rules that are already in your htaccess file?

Comment: It shouldn't do because your one used the last flag and I put it before everything else. The current htaccess (without your additions) is `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`